# Library GitHub for asp.net core

Tags: git, github, asp.net-core

Подскажите, существует ли либа для работы с гитхабом, которая позволяет работать со статистикой открытого репозитория? К примеру: сканировать каждый файл и подсчитывать общее число коммитов для каждого файла?

Comment: Asp.net core предназначен для создания веб-серверов, а не клиентов.

Comment: @free_ze никто не запрещает вывести клиентский интерфейс на веб старницу

Comment: @adrug, никто не запрещает выводить хоть в консоль. Так к чему тогда в вопросе asp.net core?

Comment: @free_ze думаю каждый вначале не умел задавать вопросы

Comment: @adrug, _если вы хотите пофлудить вне рамок вопроса - [местные чаты](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) или даже [мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com) - к вашим услугам_

Comment: @free_ze. я задал конкретный вопрос. На который можно ответить "да есть, вот API, которое поможет тебе в этом" либо "НЕТ", третьего не дано

Comment: Вы обратили внимание, что на вопрос никто так и не ответил за сутки? Расшифровываю свое третье: если заменить asp.net core на просто C#, то вопрос получит больше релевантных просмотров.

Comment: К глубочайшему сожалению, ответ на этот вопрос я нашел сам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 библиотеки, которые поддерживают .Net 4.5+. Обе библиотеки представляют API для работы с Github под платформу Asp.net

https://github.com/henon/GitSharp
http://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Но никакой интеграции с ASP.NET указанные библиотеки все же не предлагают. Кроме того, они предназначены для Git, а не GitHub.